# Incorrect data returned when reading from pipe

Tags: c, pipe, fork, ipc

I am sending data from a sender process to a receiver process using Pipes. After spending some good amount of time trying to solve this problem, still can't figure it out.

Writing to the pipe works, but on reading from the pipe, I get "nothing". Below is my code and output. For simplicity, I am only reading out the first byte (a single alphabet) from the pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void GenerateData();
void WriteData();
void ReadData();

int fildes[2];
char* buff; 
char*  alphab;
char* alphabt;              
int i, n;
int pid_rcv = -1;



main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    buff = (char*) malloc(26);

    pipe(fildes);               //pipe with two file descriptors (for write and read)

    printf("---IPC---\n");
    printf("Pipe_in descrp: %i\n", fildes[1]);
    printf("Pipe_out descrp: %i\n", fildes[0]);

    //Generate alphabets A - Z
    GenerateData();


    //Fork child (receiver). Parent will be sender
    pid_rcv = fork();

    if( pid_rcv < 0 )
    {
        /* check for error while forking */
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid_rcv == 0)
    {
        /* this is the receiver process */
        printf("Receiver's PID: %i\n", getpid());

        close(fildes[1]);                               //close write end of pipe

        ReadData();                                     //read then print alphabet from pipe

        exit(0);                                        //exit receiver
    }
    else 
    {
        /* this is the sender process */
        printf("Sender's PID: %i\n", getpid());

        close(fildes[0]);                               //close read end of pipe

        WriteData();                                    //write alphabets to pipe at 1 sec intervals
        //close(fildes[1]);                                 //close write pipe


        wait(NULL);                                 //wait for receiver process to finish   
    }


    //terminate
    free(buff);
    printf("End of IPC program.\n");
    return 0;
}


void GenerateData()
{
    //ASCII letters from A to Z. Buffer size of 26
    n = 65;
    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        buff[i] = (char) n;
        n++;
    }

    //display generated data
    printf("Buffer: ");
    for(i=0; i<26; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", (char) buff[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} 

void WriteData()
{
    printf("Writing data to pipe...\n");    
    alphab = (char*) malloc(1); 

    for(i=25; i>=0; i--)                                    //reverse order
    {
        alphab[0] = (char) buff[i];

        write(fildes[1], &alphab, sizeof(char));            //write an alphabet to pipe
        printf("%c", alphab[0]);
        sleep(1);                       
    }
    printf("\nDone writing data to pipe.\n");

    free(alphab);
}

void ReadData()
{
    int numbBytes;
    printf("Attempting to read data from pipe...\n");
    alphabt = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)); 

    numbBytes= read(fildes[0], alphabt, sizeof(char));

    printf("Number of bytes read=%d\n", numbBytes);
    printf("Read data: %c\n", (char) *alphabt);

    free(alphabt);  
}
```

---

```
---IPC---
Pipe_in descrp: 4
Pipe_out descrp: 3
Buffer: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Sender's PID: 5195
Writing data to pipe.
ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
Done writing data to pipe. 
Receiver's PID: 4842
Attempting to read data from pipe...
Number of bytes read=1
Read data: 0
End of IPC program.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in here, in `WriteData`:

```
write(fildes[1], &alphab, sizeof(char));
```

`alphab` is a `char *`, and you're passing in the address of that variable, a `char **`.  Just pass in `alphab` and the character you want will be written.

```
write(fildes[1], alphab, sizeof(char));
```

Output:

```
---IPC---
Pipe_in descrp: 4
Pipe_out descrp: 3
Buffer: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Receiver's PID: 21523
Attempting to read data from pipe...
Sender's PID: 21522
Writing data to pipe...
Number of bytes read=1
Read data: Z
```

Comment: Thanks! Very silly mistake from my part. Thanks again. 
The output now: `ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA`